# Restore LVM if VG is not consistent (XenServer 5.6.1)

Tags: lvm, software-raid, mdadm, xenserver, restore

i have a VG that uses the PVs /dev/md1 and /dev/md2. **Now one hdd failed in /dev/md1**:

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda3[0]
      382320128 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sdc4[0] sdd4[1]
      1562805632 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      4194240 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

since that, **I get the following LVM error**:

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# pvscan
  WARNING: Volume Group VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca is not consistent
  PV /dev/md1   VG VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca   lvm2 [364.61 GB / 150.25 GB free]
  PV /dev/md2   VG VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca   lvm2 [1.46 TB / 1.35 TB free]
  Total: 2 [1.81 TB] / in use: 2 [1.81 TB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

I tried `vgcfgrestore --file /etc/lvm/backup/VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca`, but without success.

**If I execeute `vgscan` I get**:

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Volume group "VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca" inconsistent, run as master to correct
*** glibc detected *** vgscan: corrupted double-linked list: 0x09048780 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb75b9629]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0xb75b99e9]
/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02(dm_pool_destroy+0x3b)[0xb779bd5b]
vgscan(vg_release+0x38)[0x80a8dc8]
vgscan[0x806cc2a]
vgscan(process_each_vg+0x12c)[0x806d96c]
vgscan(vgscan+0x13c)[0x80755ec]
vgscan(lvm_run_command+0x11e5)[0x8060175]
vgscan(lvm2_main+0x4ca)[0x806067a]
vgscan(main+0x32)[0x80772d2]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0xb7565e9c]
vgscan[0x8053421]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-080f9000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 478343     /usr/sbin/lvm
080f9000-080fe000 rw-p 000b1000 09:00 478343     /usr/sbin/lvm
080fe000-08105000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
09003000-09068000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7200000-b7221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7221000-b7300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b7336000-b7341000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327931     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
b7341000-b7342000 rw-p 0000a000 09:00 327931     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
b7347000-b734e000 r--s 00000000 09:00 410934     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b734e000-b754e000 r--p 00000000 09:00 410974     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b754e000-b7550000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7550000-b76a2000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b76a2000-b76a4000 r--p 00152000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b76a4000-b76a5000 rw-p 00154000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b76a5000-b76a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76a8000-b76e8000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 410540     /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.5
b76e8000-b76f0000 rw-p 00040000 09:00 410540     /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.5
b76f0000-b76f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76f1000-b76f4000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b76f4000-b76f5000 r--p 00002000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b76f5000-b76f6000 rw-p 00003000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b76f6000-b7731000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327957     /lib/libsepol.so.1
b7731000-b7732000 rw-p 0003b000 09:00 327957     /lib/libsepol.so.1
b7732000-b773c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b773c000-b7752000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327956     /lib/libselinux.so.1
b7752000-b7754000 rw-p 00015000 09:00 327956     /lib/libselinux.so.1
b7754000-b7783000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 410572     /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
b7783000-b7787000 rw-p 0002f000 09:00 410572     /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
b7787000-b7789000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7789000-b77a8000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327920     /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02
b77a8000-b77aa000 rw-p 0001e000 09:00 327920     /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02
b77aa000-b77bf000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b77bf000-b77c0000 r--p 00015000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b77c0000-b77c1000 rw-p 00016000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b77c1000-b77c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77c3000-b77c7000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327918     /lib/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
b77c7000-b77c8000 rw-p 00003000 09:00 327918     /lib/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
b77cb000-b77cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77cc000-b77cd000 r--p 00796000 09:00 410974     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b77cd000-b77ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b77ce000-b77cf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77cf000-b77ea000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
b77ea000-b77eb000 r--p 0001a000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
b77eb000-b77ec000 rw-p 0001b000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
bfd24000-bfd39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

Is there any possibility to restore the LVs on this VG? What does `run as master to correct` mean?

**EDIT**

this ist the output of `mdadm -D /dev/md1`

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 22 23:14:42 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 382320128 (364.61 GiB 391.50 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 382320128 (364.61 GiB 391.50 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Dec  7 01:25:25 2013
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 3d3c12fd:51ab6cd6:83470809:bba18a55
         Events : 0.49196839

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

**EDIT2**

Raid /dev/md1 is now clean again

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 22 23:14:42 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 382320128 (364.61 GiB 391.50 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 382320128 (364.61 GiB 391.50 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Dec  7 09:14:22 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 3d3c12fd:51ab6cd6:83470809:bba18a55
         Events : 0.49196863

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       67        1      active sync   /dev/sde3
```

**EDIT3**

if i want to activate the VG i get a different error message:

```
[root@xenserver1 ~]# vgchange VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca -ay
  Volume group "VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca" inconsistent, run as master to correct
*** glibc detected *** vgchange: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0a033468 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb74e05a5]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0xb74e09e9]
/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02(dm_pool_destroy+0x3b)[0xb76c2d5b]
vgchange(vg_release+0x38)[0x80a8dc8]
vgchange[0x806cc2a]
vgchange(process_each_vg+0x3b5)[0x806dbf5]
vgchange(vgchange+0x347)[0x806ee37]
vgchange(lvm_run_command+0x11e5)[0x8060175]
vgchange(lvm2_main+0x4ca)[0x806067a]
vgchange(main+0x32)[0x80772d2]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0xb748ce9c]
vgchange[0x8053421]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-080f9000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 478343     /usr/sbin/lvm
080f9000-080fe000 rw-p 000b1000 09:00 478343     /usr/sbin/lvm
080fe000-08105000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
09ff1000-0a058000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b725d000-b7268000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327931     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
b7268000-b7269000 rw-p 0000a000 09:00 327931     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
b726e000-b7275000 r--s 00000000 09:00 410934     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b7275000-b7475000 r--p 00000000 09:00 410974     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b7475000-b7477000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7477000-b75c9000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b75c9000-b75cb000 r--p 00152000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b75cb000-b75cc000 rw-p 00154000 09:00 327906     /lib/libc-2.5.so
b75cc000-b75cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75cf000-b760f000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 410540     /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.5
b760f000-b7617000 rw-p 00040000 09:00 410540     /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5.5
b7617000-b7618000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7618000-b761b000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b761b000-b761c000 r--p 00002000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b761c000-b761d000 rw-p 00003000 09:00 327921     /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b761d000-b7658000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327957     /lib/libsepol.so.1
b7658000-b7659000 rw-p 0003b000 09:00 327957     /lib/libsepol.so.1
b7659000-b7663000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7663000-b7679000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327956     /lib/libselinux.so.1
b7679000-b767b000 rw-p 00015000 09:00 327956     /lib/libselinux.so.1
b767b000-b76aa000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 410572     /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
b76aa000-b76ae000 rw-p 0002f000 09:00 410572     /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
b76ae000-b76b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76b0000-b76cf000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327920     /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02
b76cf000-b76d1000 rw-p 0001e000 09:00 327920     /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02
b76d1000-b76e6000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b76e6000-b76e7000 r--p 00015000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b76e7000-b76e8000 rw-p 00016000 09:00 327953     /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b76e8000-b76ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76ea000-b76ee000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327918     /lib/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
b76ee000-b76ef000 rw-p 00003000 09:00 327918     /lib/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02
b76f3000-b76f4000 r--p 00796000 09:00 410974     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b76f4000-b76f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b76f5000-b76f6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b76f6000-b7711000 r-xp 00000000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7711000-b7712000 r--p 0001a000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7712000-b7713000 rw-p 0001b000 09:00 327897     /lib/ld-2.5.so
bff17000-bff2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

Comment: What the OS? You have to rebuild that raid1 and for md1 to clear the glibc errror most likely after that your LVM VG should be fine again.

Comment: I've added the mdadm output - shouldn't it be possible to go with a degraded array until i have the new disk?

Comment: by the way: the OS is Citrix XenServer 5.6.1 (CentOS)

Comment: ok, I rebuilt the array (it is in clean state now) - but i still get the "WARNING: Volume Group VG_XenStorage-00c0d7a2-7054-c4fc-414a-e6c6a43b9cca is not consistent" message if I do pvscan

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you paste what "vgdisplay" shows?